# what is the default pattern for TCL trying to match?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following code in TCL:

```
""
```

and when I am trying to match the following output:

```
"hello world"
```

and it matches, what does `""` matches?

Comment: I don't think that `""` is a code. What exactly do you have?

Comment: Usually regexp are unbound. You you try to match noting in the string.

Comment: @Jerry I am trying to use regex "" to match string "hello world"

Comment: It will match because you're not looking for anything in the string. I don't think you will find this expression useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, "" matches the empty string before the "h".

I assume your command is: `regexp "" "hello world"`

Tcl regular expressions are well documented: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm and in the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

---

`regexp` will find an empty string at all these places:

```
 h e l l o   w o r l d
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Comment: Every string, including the empty string, contains the empty string.

Comment: at the beginning of the string? how many empty string it contains? what about in the "Hello World", after the World, is there a empty string?

Comment: at the beginning and end of the string as well as between each character.